# Trouble with photo syncing between iPhone and iPad

Tags: photos, data-transfer

Sometimes when I take photos in my iPhone 5s they automatically show up on my iPad. But most of the time they don't.

How can I analyze and solve this?

Comment: You had two questions in here. This site works better when there is only one question per question. That way, it's easier for other people to find solutions if they have the same problem. I've edited out your second question, but feel free to ask it separately.

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

Using iCloud:
- On your iPhone go to Settings > iCloud > Storage & Backup
- Turn iCloud Backup on and wait for it to back up completely
- If you've already used your iPad, on there go to Settings > General > Reset, tap Erase All Content and Settings
- When you're setting up the iPad, it will ask if you want to restore from an iCloud backup—just choose the iPhone backup

Using a computer with iTunes:
- Sync your iPhone with iTunes—this will also make a backup
- If you've already used your iPad, on there go to Settings > General > Reset, tap Erase All Content and Settings
- Connect your iPad to your computer and follow the steps in iTunes to restore from the iPhone backup

Follow this guide with steps and demo if you need it:
[How to Transfer Photos from iPhone to iPad](http://transferphone.com/iphone-photos-to-ipad.html)

Comment: How does a full restore address the issue stated in the question?